# Let $G$ be a group and we suppose that the commutator of $G$ has order $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and we suppose that the commutator of $G$ has order $m$. I want to show that each element of $G$ has at most $m$ different conjugates. That means that $\left|x^G\right|\leq m$ for all $x\in G$ where x^G={z ∈ G : z ∼ x} = {z ∈ G : z = gxg−1 for some g ∈ G}. I have no idea to prove this, I do not know how can I start.

Comment: What is the "switch" of a group? (I assume that by $x^G$ you mean the set of conjugacy classes of $x$, but correct me if I'm wrong - I do not recognize this notation.)

Comment: Swith is the commutator of G, and x^G={z ∈ G : z ∼ x} = {z ∈ G : z = gxg−1 for some g ∈ G}

Comment: Then why not call it "the commutator or derived subgroup",  like all the world does?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$gxg^{-1}=[g,x]x\ \in [G,G]x\,.$$

Comment: Much more succinct than the way I thought about it! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/proof strategy:** If $x$ and $y$ are in the same conjugacy class, then $x$ and $y$ have the same image under the natural map $\pi : G\to G^{ab} := G/[G,G]$ (why?). Use this to obtain a relationship between $x^G$ and $\pi^{-1}(x[G,G])$, and consider the size of $\pi^{-1}(x[G,G])$.